# How to use cloud-init with Terraform?

Tags: terraform, cloud-init

I am working with Digital Ocean and Terraform and I already can automate the domain, subdomain, network preferences and the host but there is a section called `User data` that looks like this:

[image: User data]

The description of that field says `Allows the use of Cloud-init to configure your droplet`. Looking around I found the [documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

How to take advantage of this while using [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Cloud-init files are essentially bootstrap codes, that run before each startup, and can - among others - modify files, set up services, create users, etc.

Not all types of droplets support all functionalities of cloud-init, for example CoreOS uses it's own implementation, with a very limited subset of valid values.

To use this in terraform, simply provide the cloud-init file during droplet creation:

`main.tf`:

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "web" {
  image              = "coreos-stable"
  name               = "web"
  region             = "lon1"
  size               = "2gb"
  private_networking = true
  ssh_keys           = ["${digitalocean_ssh_key.dodemo.id}"]
  user_data          = "${file("web.conf")}"
}
```

`web.conf`:

```
#cloud-config
coreos:
  units:
    - name: "etcd2.service"
      command: "start"
    - name: "fleet.service"
      command: "start"
```

This will for example create a droplet, where CoreOS will run etcd2 and fleet during startup

You can find some more examples [in this repository](https://github.com/sztupy/doclusterdemo/tree/master/terraform), where I show how one can use these configuration options to set up some simple docker based services on CoreOS

Answer (score 6):

When you create an Auto Scaling group with Terraform, you can specify the `user_data` to be used by instances created by this ASG. Documented here - https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/launch_configuration.html#user_data

You can also create a single EC2 instance, and provide `user_data` to be used - https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#user_data

The AWS EC2 documentation explains how `user_data` is passed to the `cloud-init` service which is running on most Linux distributions available as AMIs on AWS - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-cloud-init