# terraform - how should I clone my code repo?

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a very simple terraform configuration. I boot up an aws instance of Ubuntu trusty and assign a security group.

My question is who is responsible of getting the latest code from my code repo? is it a bash script in terraform `user_data` argument or should I make a modified AMI that has a bash script to pull the code repo.

Basically my repo has docker configuration in it and all i need is to clone and do `docker-compose -f env.yml up`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the clone of the repo and the execution of docker-compose in several ways.

You are right when you think that cloud-init could do that. Check [this link](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/10/how-to-use-cloud-init-with-terraform) for more information